# Pjax saving custom state data

Tags: state, pjax

I'm using Pjax in a site that I'm building, and after searching all over, I haven't been able to find a way to save custom data, for retrieving later.
This is my code:

```
var myData = {
        tst1: "some value",
        tst2: "some other value"
    };
$(document).pjax('a[pjax]', '#content', { //id to be loaded into
        fragment: '#content', //id to be loaded
        timeout: 3000,
        data: myData
    });
```

When I try to log event.state.data on a "pjax:popstate" event, I get undefined.

```
$(document).bind("pjax:popstate", function(event) {
        console.log(event.state.data);
});
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong please?

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. This is rather weird that there is nothing to find about this topic (especially since it is standard in `history.pushstate`)

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to achieve here? `pjax:popstate` is a browser event for the forward/back button as per: https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax#events and does not accept any options.

Syntax for options: `$(document).pjax(delegation selector, container selector, options object)`.

Events under PJAX fire like this: `fire('pjax:end', [xhr, options])`, so accessing an option should work with `options.option` in your case:

```
$(document).bind("pjax_event", function(xhr, options) {
    console.log(options.data);
```

});

Not tested, though. Would require more info.